# Can't retrieve username of user in Hubot

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, hubot

I can't seem to make this work, I'm just trying to print out the username of people who've just entered

```
robot.enter (msg) ->
   msg.send "#{msg.user.name}"
```

Comment: it does, because if i replace the insides of "" with Hello it gets printed.

Answer (score 26):

I'd guess that you're looking at the wrong thing. The Hubot scripting interface isn't exactly documented but [`notify.coffee` in the examples](https://github.com/github/hubot-scripts/blob/master/src/scripts/notify.coffee#L23) says this:

```
module.exports = (robot) ->
  robot.hear /@(\w+)/i, (msg) ->
    sender   = msg.message.user.name.toLowerCase()
    #...
```

So you probably want to look at `msg.message` instead of `msg`:

```
robot.enter (msg) ->
   msg.send "#{msg.message.user.name}"
```